# To Replace the File in available in Archive folder with the new one

Tags: vba, filesystemobject

Below mentioned code is successfully creating an updated "Datewise folder" and it automatically moves the files in it. However i just need a small amendment.

Currently if the file with the same exact name is available in Destination Folder it does not move the file and file stays in Source Folder, however can anyone please help and amend the code so that if a file which is already available in Destination folder and if it comes again in Source folder the code should replace the new file with the previously available file

```
Sub moveAllFilesInDateFolderIfNotExist()

 Dim DateFold As String, fileName As String, objFSO As Object

 Const sFolderPath As String = "E:\Uploading\Source"

 Const dFolderPath As String = "E:\Uploading\Archive"

 DateFold = dFolderPath & "\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") ' create the folder if it does not exist


 If Dir(DateFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir DateFold

 fileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "\*.*")
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
 Do While fileName <> ""

    If Not objFSO.FileExists(DateFold & "\" & fileName) Then

        Name sFolderPath & "\" & fileName As DateFold & "\" & fileName

    End If

    fileName = Dir

 Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru please see this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next updated code. `Name` does not have a parameter able to make it overwriting. But the code can `kill` (delete) the file if it exists and use the method **after that**:

```
Sub moveAllFilesInDateFolderIfNotExist()

 Dim DateFold As String, fileName As String, objFSO As Object

 Const sFolderPath As String = "E:\Uploading\Source"

 Const dFolderPath As String = "E:\Uploading\Archive"

 DateFold = dFolderPath & "\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") ' create the folder if it does not exist


 If Dir(DateFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir DateFold

 fileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "\*.*")
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
 Do While fileName <> ""

    If Not objFSO.FileExists(DateFold & "\" & fileName) Then
        Name sFolderPath & "\" & fileName As DateFold & "\" & fileName
    Else
        kill DateFold & "\" & fileName
        Name sFolderPath & "\" & fileName As DateFold & "\" & fileName
    End If

    fileName = Dir

 Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: @Salman Shafi Did you test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need? The code is not tested, but it should work. It  was only  a small modifications, deleting the file if exists prior to move the new one...